# How to create DATE datatype in a create query in oracle database?

Tags: oracle, date-format

Please explain how to write a create query where i can write a spcific date in a specific format (suppose dd/MM/yy) in oracle. Suppose i need my columns in my table ORDERS to be-
order_id, order_date, quantity

Comment: `DATE '2014-09-07'` or `to_date('2014-09-07', 'yyyy-mm-dd')`. Please read the manual. Oh and: DATE columns do ***NOT*** have "a format".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [the documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e40540/tablecls.htm#CNCPT113):

> "The database stores dates internally as numbers. Dates are stored in
>   fixed-length fields of 7 bytes each, corresponding to century, year,
>   month, day, hour, minute, and second."

And what that looks like:

```
SQL> select dump(sysdate) from dual
  2  /

DUMP(SYSDATE)
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
Typ=13 Len=8: 222,7,9,7,2,48,32,0

SQL>
```

Which actually looks like eight bytes but interestingly a date is nine bytes long:

```
SQL> select lengthb(sysdate) from dual
  2  /

LENGTHB(SYSDATE)
----------------
               9

SQL>
```

Anyway, storage is fixed and entirely independent of the displaying of dates.

The default date format is governed by the [NLS_DATETIME_FORMAT](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/appdev.112/e10766/tdddg_globalization.htm#TDDDG62410), which is defaulted by the NLS_TERRITORY setting. This is how Oracle determines Currencym, number, formats, days of the week  and so on.  Find out more by reading the [Globalization Support guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E11882_01/server.112/e10729/toc.htm).

If you want a different default format mask for your dates this can be set at the database level.  This is a big decision. Fortunately it can also be set at a more granular level:

```
SQL> select sysdate from dual
  2  /

SYSDATE
---------
07-SEP-14

SQL> alter session set nls_date_format='Month DD YYYY HH12:MI AM'
  2  /

Session altered.

SQL> select sysdate from dual
  2  /

SYSDATE
--------------------------
September 07 2014 03:05 AM

SQL>
```

As far as input of dates goes, Oracle expects strings containing dates to have the same format as that specified by the NLS_DATE_FORMAT.  If this is not the case then we have to apply a conversion using the TO_DATE() function and supplying the mask of the string:

```
SQL> select to_date('31/05/14','DD/MM/YY') from dual
  2  /

TO_DATE('31/05/14','DD/MM/
--------------------------
May       31 2014 12:00 AM

SQL>
```

Comment: Sir i do not want to use the sysdate. If possible please explain how to insert the date in dd/MM/yyyy.

Comment: I just used sysdate as a handy way of showing the structure of a date.  My last example shows how to pass a string with a date value which is not in the default format.

Comment: You are giving me the select query. I was talking about the insert query about how to insert date in any particular format.